# Degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3 + 2 \sqrt{2}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory

In the text by Dummit and Foote, there is the following exercise in chapter 13:

> Determine the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}\big(\sqrt{3 + 2 \sqrt{2}}\big)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

To solve this problem, I proceeded by letting $\alpha = \sqrt{3 + 2 \sqrt{2}}$ and then computing $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$.  Assuming I did this correctly, one gets 
\begin{equation*}
\alpha^2 = 3 + 2 \sqrt{2} \quad \text { and } \quad \alpha^4 = 17 + 12 \sqrt{2}
\end{equation*}

It follows from this that the polynomial $f(x) = x^4 - 6x^2 + 1$ has $\alpha$ as a root.  The only divisors of the constant term are $1$ and $-1$, and $f(\pm1) \neq 0$.  By the Rational Roots Test, we should have $f$ be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so that the answer to the question is $4$.

However, I was looking at [this write up](https://positron0802.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/abstract-algebra-dummit-foote-chapter-13-field-theory-solutions.pdf)  of solutions, and here the answer is given as $2$.  So I am guessing there is some error in my "proof" that the degree is $4$, but can't seem to find what I did incorrectly...

Comment: Careful: lack of roots for quartic polynomials does not guarantee irreducibility.  That only holds with quadratics and cubics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to note that
$$ (1+\sqrt{2})^2=1+2\sqrt{2}+2=3+2\sqrt{2}$$
so in fact $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

The problem with your argument is that even if a quartic polynomial has no rational roots, it can still be reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it could be a product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials.

Comment: In fact, it is true for no degrees other than $2$ and $3$. What's going on is that every polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ factors (uniquely!) into the product of irreducible polynomials of degree $\leq 3$. When the degree of your polynomial is $2$ or $3$ that means that every reducible polynomial has at least one linear factor, but not for degree $>3$. You likely have the tools at your disposal to prove this very interesting fact about polynomials.

Comment: @carmichael561  I see your point about the fallacy of the implication ($f$ has no rational roots) $\implies$ ($f$ is irreducible) when $f$ is of degree $4$.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Sam Y.: The argument in the solution manual looks ok to me, it just uses a previous exercise which I was unaware of when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @carmichael561  Sorry, I got mixed up.  Just forget that previous comment.  Great answer.  Thanks.